# Делаю приложение на java, не знаю как одним оператором if проверить string на наличие алфавитных символов

Tags: java, строки

Делаю простое приложение, в котором есть настройки, и в них можно вписать любое значение. Я использовал метод что бы строку перевести в int значение, и надо сделать так, что бы если в строке присутствуют алфавитные символы, выводило в консоль ошибку.

```
if (!field.getText().contains(...)){
numb = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
```

}

Comment: Да просто оберните в try/catch с отловом NumberFormatException. Если исключение возникает - выводите ошибку.

Comment: спасибо, забыл как-то про try-catch

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать регулярное выражение для проверки формата при помощи `String::matches`:

```java
// формат целого числа с необязательным знаком
if (field.getText().matches("[-+]?\\d+")) { 
    numb = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
}
```

Также можно перед проверкой формата обрезать лишние пробелы, используя `String::trim`:

```java
String txt = field.getText().trim();
if (txt.matches("[-+]?\\d+")) { // формат целого числа с необязательным знаком
    numb = Integer.parseInt(txt);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, работает

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезным, можете поставить зелёную галочку, она находится слева от ответа.